# Intel HAXM installation error - This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology

Tags: android, xamarin, intel, virtualization, visual-studio-2017

Ok, head's mashed.

Trying to install Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager and get the:

["Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager error"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c89rp.png)

Virtualization is enabled:
[CPU Stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czRpx.png)

I've ran the following commands as suggested in previous answers to posts about the same issue:

bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off

bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOn

Hyper-V, which the disabling of seems to solve a lot of problems, doesn't exist on my pc, as trying to disable it produces the error Hyper-v missing

It's not like I don't know what I'm doing, I've successfully installed this on 6 PCs at work.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What processors do you have on the computers?

Comment: AMD A8-6410 APU with AMD
Cores: 4
Logical Processors: 4

Comment: Kindly check the below pdf http://modernievirt.blob.core.windows.net/vhd/release_notes_license_terms_1_5_15.pdf

Comment: Haxm is unfortunately only for intel processors.  Maybe you can use the hyper-v emulators or genymotion emulators instead